# Positioning an embedded YouTube player

Tags: javascript, css, youtube

I am creating an interactive video site and have this function:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var done = false;
var player;

function videoChosen(btnid) {   
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0,'autohide':2,'disablekb':1,'modestbranding':1,'fs':0 },
      videoId: btnid,
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }


    });
}
```

But I can't find a way to change the video player position (it keeps loading on the top left side of the browser). Is there a way using CSS targeting the player that was summoned using the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like possibly you're missing the div for your player, i.e 
`<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>`

Have a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started).  Your player will take the place of this div, as it says.  So, place the div where you want the player.

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow i was sure i read everything about it.
and Its working! thanks :)